# How to create QML object within a singleton?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have defined a QML object under `MyQMLObject.qml`. This QML file looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Item {
  id: rootItem
  implicitWidth: LayoutUtils.maxImplicitWidth(children)
  implicitHeight: LayoutUtils.maxImplicitHeight(children)

  Text {
    id: text1
  }
  Text {
    id: text2
  }
  // ...
  Text {
    id: textN
  }
}
```

The text is added dynamically when the application starts. For each language different text is added, there for the width of the `rootItem` varies by the chosen language. I would like to somehow create `MyQMLObject` only once at application startup without even visualizing it and save its actual width in a singleton for example so I can reuse that value throughout my code without creating `MyQMLObject` more then once. How could I achieve this?

Right now I have a singleton QML file, which holds a `QtObject` which contains some constant values. Can I somehow create an instance of `MyQMLObject` within this singleton `QtObject`?

My singleton `Style.qml` looks like this:

```
pragma Singleton

import QtQuick 2.4

QtObject {
  readonly property int maxWidth: 400
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use QML to calcuate the text size?

Comment: Not necessarily. Thx for the alternative suggestion!

Comment: Why not simply use `text1.paintedWidth`?

Comment: @sk2212: I simplified the question with having only text, but in general I want it to work on more complex GUI items also.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Firstly, if possible, you could use a `Column` instead of manually calculating the maximum width:

**MyQMLObject.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4

Column {
    Text {
        text: "blah"
    }
    Text {
        text: "blahblah"
    }
}
```

You can use [dynamic object creation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) to create the temporary `Column` item:

**Style.qml**

```
pragma Singleton

import QtQuick 2.4

QtObject {
    readonly property int maxWidth: {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("qrc:/MyQMLObject.qml");
        if (component.status === Component.Error) {
            console.error(component.errorString());
            return 0;
        }

        return component.createObject().width;
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import App 1.0

Window {
    visible: true

    Component.onCompleted: print(Style.maxWidth)
}
```

Then, [register the singleton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType-2):

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtQml>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterSingletonType(QUrl("qrc:///Style.qml"), "App", 1, 0, "Style");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

---

However, note that this approach could be improved by calculating the maximum width from C++, eliminating the need to construct an item only to throw it away. Working off [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType-1):

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtQml>

class Style : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int maxWidth READ maxWidth CONSTANT)

public:
    Style(QObject* parent = 0) :
        QObject(parent),
        mMaxWidth(0)
    {
        QFontMetrics fontMetrics(qApp->font());
        // Here is where you'd fetch the text...
        QStringList dummyText;
        dummyText << "blah" << "blahblah";
        foreach (const QString &string, dummyText) {
            const int width = fontMetrics.boundingRect(string).width();
            if (width > mMaxWidth)
                mMaxWidth = width;
        }
    }

    int maxWidth() const
    {
        return mMaxWidth;
    }

private:
    int mMaxWidth;
};

static QObject *singletonTypeProvider(QQmlEngine *, QJSEngine *)
{

    Style *style = new Style();
    return style;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterSingletonType<Style>("App", 1, 0, "Style", singletonTypeProvider);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

It uses `QFontMetrics` to calculate the [width](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-1).

`main.qml` remains unchanged.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer Mitch and also for suggesting an alternative! Will try them out right now.

Comment: I was reading in [qmldir](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html#contents-of-a-module-definition-qmldir-file) as that for me would be preferable. There it looks like you wouldn't need to use `qmlRegisterSingletonType`. It could just be omitted, because I couldn't get it to work without it.