# How do I create static class in Qt?

Tags: qt, static, qml, constants

I am developing a Qt/QML application.
All QML and graphics are in different locations. So need to create variables (path for different features).

I tried to create the same in Javascript.

```
var IMAGE_PATH.Feature1 = "//qrc:///graphics/Feature1/"
var IMAGE_PATH.Feature2 = "//qrc:///graphics/Feature2/"
var IMAGE_PATH.Feature3 = "//qrc:///graphics/Feature3/"
var IMAGE_PATH.Feature4 = "//qrc:///graphics/Feature4/"
```

By using Javascript, we need to import the same in all QML, whichever used.
To avoid this I need to create the same in Qt.
How do I create the same in Qt class?

Comment: So... what is it that you are trying to do exactly? :D If you need to create a singleton, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35522174/904422) answer should help.

Comment: Though you will still need to import that singleton in QML.

Comment: What's _import the same_ you mean?

Comment: @derM: If JavaScript file I need to import the header in all qml file.

Comment: If you use a QML or C++ singleton registered to QML - you will still need to import in every QML file. If you don't want to import it all the time, you can just have properties in the root node of your qml structure or set it from C++ as context property. By using dynamic scoping you will then (not most efficiently) find the correct paths. IMHO, import is the way to go.

Comment: Create a single Image Controller QML class that has all that junk and then just import the image controller and use it to handle all of the graphics stuff then use  find/replace in files to replace `IMAGE_PATH.FeatureX` with  `imageController.feature(X)` or whatever