# Want to connect QML types across the QML files in PyQt6

Tags: qml, pyqt6

This is a simple example of what I want to do.

```js
// main.qml

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

ApplicationWindow {
  visible: true
  width: 640
  height: 480
  title: "Example App"

  Material.theme: Material.Dark

  MyLabel {
    id: idMyLabel
    anchors.centerIn: parent
  }

  MyButton {
    anchors.top: idMyLabel.bottom
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
  }
}
```

```js
// MyLabel.qml

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

RowLayout {
  spacing: 40

  Label {
    id: idInnerLabel1
    text: "Label 1"
  }

  Label {
    id: idInnerLabel2
    text: "Label 2"
  }

  Label {
    id: idInnerLabel3
    text: "Label 3"
  }
}
```

```js
// MyButton.qml

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

Page {
  Button {
    text: "Change"
    onClicked: idInnerLabel2.text = "Changed"
  }
}
```

But, I got an error when I run this example.

> ReferenceError: idInnerLabel2 is not defined

I wanted to communicate between nested QML files. Putting them together in one file worked fine. So I was confused and I couldn't understand its inner working.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: There is no way for `MyButton` to get access to `idInnerLabel2`. Use aliases or a global singleton component instead.

Comment: Hi SMR, Could I get an example of that?

Comment: Of course, Here is an example of a [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35522174/11603485) and [alias](https://www.qt.io/product/qt6/qml-book/ch04-qmlstart-components#:~:text=We%20use%20the%20alias%20feature%20of%20QML%2C%20which%20is%20a%20way%20to%20export%20properties%20inside%20nested%20QML%20elements%20to%20the%20root%20level). BTW, I do not recommend the accepted answer's method because it is prone to error.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I'll try these methods as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both MyButton and MyLabel appear in main.qml the simplest solution would be to create a property in main.qml that both can access.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Page {
  property string txt1: "Label 1"
  property string txt2: "Label 2"
  property string txt3: "Label 3"
  MyLabel {
    id: idMyLabel
    anchors.centerIn: parent
  }

  MyButton {
    anchors.top: idMyLabel.bottom
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
  }
}

// MyLabel.qml

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

RowLayout {
  spacing: 40

  Label {
    text: txt1
  }

  Label {
    text: txt2
  }

  Label {
    text: txt3
  }
}

// MyButton.qml

import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Controls.Material

Page {
  Button {
    text: "Change"
    onClicked: txt2 = "Changed"
  }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAAC43icvVJBboMwELz7FSseQBroCamXcqqUSE1+4IBFrILXMYsaUvXvXeyAQhp67AEL74xnd8bWjUVHsKNdp4sPoWfbOEdDDutWiHdZKfgSANahVY56aMlpUwGdaZ1BtJEHVcM6esxIJkaywEgnRjowtn3YDB0BdJnxd635ijTFEV0bF8qQcm8mAysd/zP4Lfz5144IzVVgpBPaG6X4gMxpZgxe9IVdyzr30qPwL8B34l6r1ThsfGpqcZfgfaAb2WNH7WLOC/V4K7mllqy/x88g4q21VhacYAbPT4Pt29BInSnz1zOG8hBN/kTTmc2Q6f/4nB7c7CLDYFF+lKZSkS+hyWvWUGWwAy8jXEZh+B/wCfEo)